# Force Visual Studio 2015 Installer to use corporate proxy inside a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, installation, proxy, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to set up a development VM on an ESXi server for my corporation and have run into issues installing the needed software on it.

The used OS is `Windows Enterprise 2019 LTSC` and the software to be installed is `Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with Update 3`.

Requests out of the VM's network need to go through a corporate proxy (which I have absolutely no power over) to reach the outside at all, which is why I have already configured the proxy in Win10's network settings -> The usual web traffic from browsing is already being redirected, meaning browsing the web works.

I have then tried to install VS 2015 (using the `Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with Update 3` DVD iso file from Microsoft's [MSDN Page](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads)), but the setup partially failed. Some components could not be installed due to the missing internet access.

The most important thing is that I need the SDK for Windows Enterprise 2019 LTSC and of an older Windows version installed into VS along with some extensions and tools to be able to build our project. I can, however, not install anything because I cannot make VS itself or its installer use the Proxy.

I've tried what [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936478/how-to-set-proxy-in-visual-studio-2015) over on Stack Overflow suggested but sadly it didn't work.

Is what I am trying to do not possible because a proxy is meant to only reroute web traffic and the VS installer is not considered web traffic? Microsoft states [on their support page](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vs-2019) that the requests during install all run on 443/80 which should work with a proxy..

What can I try to install the needed software?

Answer (score 0):

As VS2015 is partially installed, except for some components,
you may complete the installation by initiating a repair from
*Control Panel > Programs and Features*.
Before doing that, you should configure VS2015 to use the proxy.

I quote here a Stack Overflow answer for doing this configuration
from the article
[How to set proxy in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41936608/165358):

> Find `devenv.exe.config` in your installation directory.
>
> Now open this text file and add the node `<defaultProxy>` inside the
> node `<system.net>`.
>
> ```
> <system.net>
> <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
>     <proxy bypassonlocal="true" proxyaddress="http://yourproxyaddress.net:8080" />
> </defaultProxy>
> </system.net>
> ```
>
> If your proxy requires authentication, you should add those as
> parameters in the proxy URL
>
> ```
> <system.net>
> <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
>     <proxy bypassonlocal="true" proxyaddress="http://Username:Password@yourproxyaddress.net:8080" />
> </defaultProxy>
> </system.net>
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work me as it is the exact same thread I've mentioned in my question already. The line "I've tried what this post over on SO suggested" has the link to this very post. I am trying the repair now nevertheless and it seems to do stuff, will be in touch later again.

Comment: So the repair process really seems to have fixed the incorrect installation, however hitting   "change" in the VS installer still ends in a warning about having no internet access.

Comment: Is the installation fixed and is now usable?

Comment: Since I am still not able to install any of the dependencies I need to work with our project, no, it is not usable for me. VS is installed and can be opened though.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a dependency?

Comment: An extension to build our installer packages for example, can't look into the exact name now though since I do not have access to my work pc. I think it was literally called "VS2015 InstallerProjects"

Comment: If you don't have bandwidth problems, you can perhaps download all of the VS ISO and install from that. You may also [Create an offline installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) (the method hasn't changed much since 2015, only some components).

Comment: I have already used an offline VS ISO installation.

Comment: Your dependency is probably [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) which is downloadable and doesn't exist in the ISO, so no problem with installing it.

Comment: Another dependancy that's giving me issues now is "Visual C++ MFC for x86/x64" which I just can't install because my VS installer refuses to use the configured proxy. I can't work like this.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003428/mfc-multibyte-add-on-for-visual-studio-2015-express-for-desktop).

Comment: Thank you for your further assistance with this, but unfortunately, the linked post does not give me anything. The issue is that the installer has no internet connection because it is not using the proxy, rendering the solutions listed there useless to me. I cannot install anything using the VS installer.